# boxplot with filtered values

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I am new to coding and want to create boxplots based on my data.

For that, I want to filter a boxplot by specific values:

My data structure is called "Auswertungen" and is structured like this:

```
Participant  Donation  Treatment  Manipulation
1             0           1          passed
2            0.4          2          passed
3            0.2          2          failed
4             0           3          failed 
5            0.3          3          passed
```

now I want to plot the Donations based on the Treatments, using a boxplot. I want to graphs, one with all data points and one without those who failed the manipulation.

I found something like

```
boxplot(Donation ~ Treatment) 
with(subset(Auswertungen, Manipulation == "passed"), boxplot(Donation ~ Treatment))
```

but the second formula is exactly showing me the same boxplots as before, so I guess the subset is not working?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is roughly structured like this:

```
set.seed(222)
Donation <- abs(rnorm(20))
Treatment <- sample(1:3, 20, replace = T)
Manipulation <- sample(c("passed", "failed"), 20, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(Donation, Treatment, Manipulation)
df
      Donation Treatment Manipulation
1  1.487757090         3       passed
2  0.001891901         2       failed
3  1.381020790         1       failed
4  0.380213631         3       passed
5  0.184136230         1       failed
6  0.246895883         3       passed
7  1.215560910         3       failed
8  1.561405098         1       failed
9  0.427310197         2       passed
10 1.201023506         3       passed
11 1.052458495         2       passed
12 1.305063566         2       failed
13 0.692607634         3       failed
14 0.602648854         3       failed
15 0.197753074         2       failed
16 1.185874517         2       passed
17 2.005512989         3       passed
18 0.007509885         2       passed
19 0.519490356         2       failed
20 0.746295471         2       failed
```

And you want to have two boxplots, you can first define a two-panel layout:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
```

And then fill your two boxplots into it, the first one unfiltered:

```
boxplot(df$Donation ~ df$Treatment)
```

and the second filtered on the condition that `Manipulation=="passed"`:

```
boxplot((df$Donation[df$Manipulation=="passed"] ~ df$Treatment[df$Manipulation=="passed"]))
```

The result would be something like this:
[image]

Comment: or `boxplot(Donation ~ Treatment, data=Auswertungen, subset=Manipulation=="passed")` which is a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, sorry.

```
boxplot(Donation ~ Treatment)
boxplot(Donation[Manipulation == "passed"] ~ Treatment[Manipulation == "passed"]
```

Comment: The `boxplot` function does have a `subset` argument if that's any help.

Comment: I know, I tried it using the subset function (I need it based on two columns), but it didn't work.

Comment: If you're going to use the formula method of `boxplot`, you should really use the `data` argument, an the optional `subset` argument. I also wonder if you have attached to the data frame?